# expose a function in go package

Tags: go

I would like to expose a function directly from a package.
So I could call my package directly instead of mypackage.Somepublic() method.

```
package main

import (
    "mypackage"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var result = mypackage() 
    fmt.Println(result)    
}
```

In node.js, for example, you can expose a anonymous function

```
module.export = function() {
    console.log('ta da!');
}
```

or an object

```
module.export = {  
    doMagic: function() {  
        console.log('ta da!');
    }
};
```

Comment: You can't do that in Go. You can't say `import "pkg"` and then `pkg()`. Most module systems don't allow this. CommonJS is special :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While there is no direct analogy for your Node.js example, what you can do in Go is something called a "local import." Basically, a local import imports all of the items - functions, types, variables, etc - that a package exports into your local namespace so that they can be accessed as if they had been defined locally. You do this by prefacing the package name with a dot. For example:

```
import . "fmt"

func main() {
    Println("Hello!") // Same as fmt.Println("Hello!")
}
```

(See this in [action](http://play.golang.org/p/--dWV6PHYA)).

This will work for any item that `fmt` exports. You could do a similar thing with `mypackage` (this is modified from the code you posted):

```
package main

import (
    . "mypackage"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var result = Somepublic() // Equivalent to mypackage.Somepublic()
    fmt.Println(result)    
}
```

Answer (score 27):

Quoting the [answer of mko](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013529/expose-a-function-in-go-package#comment76292062_18013750) here for better visibility:

> Dear Lonely Anonymous adventurer. I guess you got here for the same reason I did. So, the basic answer is. Use capital letter in the name ;) source: [tour.golang.org/basics/3](https://tour.golang.org/basics/3) - yes, I was surprised as well. I was expecting some fancy stuff, but that's all it is. Capital letter - export, small letter - no export ;)

Comment: Thanks for this simple and effective answer

Comment: Wow I thought Go was all about explicit easy to grasp programming an here we are exporting using.. case.

Comment: I did the whole tour and remembered how channels and other stuff work but somehow forgot this simple thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Good interview question haha :)

Answer (score 8):

You need to get your structure currently .. I want to assume your content is in `src` folder

`src/main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "./mypackage"
)

func main() {
    var value mypackage.Export
    value.DoMagic()
    fmt.Printf("%s", value)

}
```

`src/mypackage/export.go`

```
package mypackage

import "fmt"

type Export struct {
}

func (c Export) DoMagic() {
    fmt.Println("Magic function was called")
}

func (c Export) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprint("ta da! \n")
}
```

Run `go run main.go` you would get

```
Magic function was called
ta da!
```

Answer (score 4):

Go [Packages](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Packages) are not what you're perhaps thinking they are.

> Go programs are constructed by linking together packages. A package in turn is constructed from one or more source files that together declare constants, types, variables and functions belonging to the package and which are accessible in all files of the same package. Those elements may be exported and used in another package.

It's not the same as e.g. `#include` etc.

Comment: Ok, I don't understand the down vote. Besides that.  

Because in go exits first-class function, I was just asking if there is such thing to export a function via package. Like you do in node.js.  Node.js require is also not the same than #include.

A valid answer could be:    
No, is not possible, but you can create a New() function an return a anonymous function from there. for example.

Comment: Dear Lonely Anonymous adventurer. I guess you got here for the same reason I did. So, the basic answer is. Use capital letter in the name ;) source: https://tour.golang.org/basics/3 - yes, I was surprised as well. I was expecting some fancy stuff, but that's all it is. Capital letter - export, small letter - no export ;)

Comment: @mko Thank-you sir!

Comment: OMG. @mko, totally what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The folder structure should be similar to below.

```
-mymodule

-mymodule/main.go

-mymodule/mypackage 

-mymodule/mypackage/mypack.go
```

main.go

```
package main
import (
        "example.com/mymodule/mypackage"
        "fmt"
)
func main() 
{
var result = mypackage.DoMagic  //With a first letter i.e 'D' capital
fmt.Println(result)    
}
```

mypack.go

```
package mypackage

import ( "fmt" )

func DoMagic () string {
  fmt.Println("Inside DoMagic")
  return "magic Done"
}
```

```
Output:

Inside DoMagic
magic Done
```